# Currently trying to setup AWS on Android studio. Getting error message on Override

Tags: java, android

I was trying to setup AWS on Android studio, currently following this step on their site. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/mobile-hub-getting-started.html#mobile-hub-add-aws-mobile-sdk-connect-to-your-backend[image: Override error]

Comment: import `
import com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSStartupHandler;`

Comment: Got it working, thanks Manoj